# Firefox or Chrome SVN Client

Tags: svn, firefox-extensions

Is there any fully function SVN client for firefox or chrome? Actually I have a lot of work on svn and internet so I am looking for some sort of addon of firefox or chrome which allows me to access svn and perform svn operations directly from the browser?

I know about one of suc kind : [Tortoise SVN firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tortoisesvn-menu/) but it is not that good to be much useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

I really depends on what you are trying to do. It looks like Tortoise extensions and Firefox plugins are your only source right now for this unless you use a paying service extesion/plugin.

Here's the link to the Tortoise Chrome Extension, but you have to have Tortoise SVN installed on your local machine in order to use it: [Open TortoiseSVN For Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mhhincgnohhopnakokkcoifmnahapihn)

Can you give some more detail to what you specifically need to do with that browser that restricts you from using native applications to browse/send commands to svn?